# Stripping "&Itemid=XX" out of my URLS using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, strip

I need to strip out a certain part of my URLS being generated and want to use .htaccess.

Some links are being appended with "&Itemid=XX" after the .html.

Example:
http://www.site.com/conferences-and-events.html&Itemid=XX

XX could be one digit or four so I guess I need a wild card for that part. I know other questions have been answered related to stripping out certain parts of URLs using .htaccess but I can't seem to figure out how to get my specific string stripped out. Any help would be appreciated and sorry for being redundant and dense.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use [URL rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) for that, something like this should work;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)&Itemid=\d{1,4}(.*) $1$2 [R]
```

Explanation: This regular expression matches anything (`(.*)`) followed by `&Itemid=` [1 to 4 decimals], followed by anything (another `(.*)`), and redirects (`[R]`) to the first anything concatenated with the second anything, thus taking out the `&Itemid=xx` part.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I should have phrased it a little better. The Itemid number could be anywhere from 1 to 4 digits, not just 1 or 4. I'm guessing that might change the string a bit. Thank you again!

Comment: @Alex `\d` means a decimal, and `{1,4}` means any amount between 1 and 4 inclusive. You might find this Regex reference to be a valuable resource: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html